# UserActivity Opening last edited file

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I get my app to open the last edited file after a click in the Windows 10 Timeline? Thanks for the help.

```
        var activityId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        UserActivityChannel channel = UserActivityChannel.GetDefault();
        UserActivity userActivity = await channel.GetOrCreateUserActivityAsync(activityId);

        userActivity.VisualElements.DisplayText = PageTitle.Text;
        if (File != null)
        {
             userActivity.VisualElements.Description = File.DisplayName;
        }
      userActivity.VisualElements.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
      userActivity.VisualElements.Content = AdaptiveCardBuilder.CreateAdaptiveCardFromJson(cardText);
      userActivity.ActivationUri = new Uri("my-app:navigate?page=" + _index);

     await userActivity.SaveAsync();

    _currentActivity?.Dispose();
    _currentActivity = userActivity.CreateSession();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [UserActivityChannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.useractivities.useractivitychannel) Class, there is a [GetRecentUserActivitiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.useractivities.useractivitychannel.getrecentuseractivitiesasync#Windows_ApplicationModel_UserActivities_UserActivityChannel_GetRecentUserActivitiesAsync_System_Int32_) method, but it only get the specified number of the most recently engaged user activities sorted by the time each user activity ended. Due to the privacy protecting policy of UWP app, your app can not get the user activities from system or other apps.

Currently, in your app, you can only operate the user activities which your app created. If the file is edited by the system or other app, you can not implement the effect you want. But if the file is operated by your app, you can try to create a user activity which is for opening the file then handle the protocol activated event in your app to open it. Maybe you should see the topic [track recently used files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders).